# Error using abstract class Task in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, abstract-class

I am trying to follow this guide to do selfie segmentation on Android (link below), but am struggling with how to use Task. When I copy and paste the code to [process the image that uses a Task<> object](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/selfie-segmentation/android#3_process_the_image) in Android Studio, I'm getting the error `Cannot implement abstract class`.

What am I doing wrong?

Note, code snippet below is abbreviated

```
class CameraFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _fragmentCameraBinding: FragmentCameraBinding? = null

    private val fragmentCameraBinding get() = _fragmentCameraBinding!!

    private var cameraUiContainerBinding: CameraUiContainerBinding? = null

    private lateinit var broadcastManager: LocalBroadcastManager

    private lateinit var mediaStoreUtils: MediaStoreUtils

    private var displayId: Int = -1
    private var lensFacing: Int = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK
    private var preview: Preview? = null
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private var imageAnalyzer: ImageAnalysis? = null
    private var camera: Camera? = null
    private var cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider? = null
    private lateinit var windowManager: WindowManager

    private val options =
        SelfieSegmenterOptions.Builder()
            .setDetectorMode(SelfieSegmenterOptions.STREAM_MODE)
            .enableRawSizeMask()
            .build()

    private val segmenter = Segmentation.getClient(options)

    // ImageAnalysis
    imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            // We request aspect ratio but no resolution
            .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            // Set initial target rotation, we will have to call this again if rotation changes
            // during the lifecycle of this use case
            .setTargetRotation(rotation)
            .build()
            // The analyzer can then be assigned to the instance
            .also {

// This raises an error "Cannot create an instance of an abstract class"
// "Function invocation 'Task<SegmentationMask>()' expected"
    Task<SegmentationMask> result = segmenter.process(image)
        .addOnSuccessListener { results ->
            // Task completed successfully
            // ...
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            // Task failed with an exception
            // ...
        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Can you tidy up your code so that it is in valid syntax? It is hard to tell whether your code has typo if you are posting invalid code in the first place.